# AUTO_UPDATE_STATISTICS fails to update stats for certain indexes. Why?

Tags: sql-server-2005

In the system I'm working on, we were seeing a particular SELECT use a clustered index scan, instead of using the index which was created for this SELECT.  I took a look at the statistics for the index, and found that they were 26 days old.  I updated the statistics with FULLSCAN.  Now the SELECT is using the index.

AUTO_UPDATE_STATISTICS has been enabled in this database the entire time.  Why did the statistics not get updated?

Looking at the STATS_DATE() output (query below):

```
SELECT 
    object_name = Object_Name(ind.object_id),
    IndexName = ind.name,
    StatisticsDate = STATS_DATE(ind.object_id, ind.index_id),
    ind.type
  FROM SYS.INDEXES ind
  order by STATS_DATE(ind.object_id, ind.index_id) desc
```

I see that many indexes were updated recently.  Some large tables which have data updates every day have not had updated statistics in weeks.

How does MSSQL 2005 decide when to update statistics when AUTO_UPDATE_STATISTICS is enabled?  The documentation states:

> A statistics update is initiated whenever the statistics used in a query execution plan fail a test for current statistics. . . Almost always, statistical information is updated when approximately 20 percent of the data rows has changed.

Can this be trusted?  Perhaps these tables are so large that the "current statistics test" is passing even though records are being inserted on a daily basis.

Comment: I bet you wish you were using SQL2K8 so you could change that index to a filtered index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a link to the algorithm details in a Microsoft whitepaper

http://technet.microsoft.com/sv-se/library/cc966419(en-us).aspx#XSLTsection130121120120

And this [quoted](http://www.sqlmonster.com/Uwe/Forum.aspx/sql-server/56414/Auto-Update-Statistics) from Erland Sommarskog:

> When you have an empty table,
>   autostats first kicks in after 500
>   rows.  From there, autostats sets in
>   when 20% of the rows have been
>   modified.  This is measure from some
>   rowmodctr.
>
> This has the effect that big tables
>   with a monotonously growing key  where
>   queries goes against the trunk have
>   their statistics updated  far too
>   rarely.
>
> Whereas small tables where all rows
>   are updated frequently, or where  or
>   rows are added and deleted, have their
>   stats updated very often,  which may
>   cause recompilation issues.

Comment: My problem is the opposite.  In a table with 11 million records, one column has a nonclustered index.  This column is int, and is populated with 0 across all records.  Our application started to insert a handful of records with nonzero values.  The index statistics were not updated automatically.  As a result, the optimizer chose to use a clustered index scan.

Answer (score 0):

The statistics are updated at 500 + 20% of the number of rows. This can take a long time some situations so it's sometimes better to do this manually.

for more info look here:
http://www.sqlserveroptimizer.com/2013/02/how-to-make-your-sql-server-index-faster-by-updating-statistics/